# Trouble with running h2o.hit_ratio_table

Tags: r, h2o, xgboost

I got this issue when I run H2o for xgboost. May I ask how can I solve this issue? Thank you.

I run this code

```
h2o.hit_ratio_table(gbm2,valid =T)
```

And I encounter this error

```
" Error in names(v) <- v_names : 
'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]"
```

Then I proceed run

```
mean(finalRF_prediction$predict==test_gb$Cover_Type)
```

and I got the error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
ERROR MESSAGE:
Name lookup of 'NULL' failed
```

My model is:

```
gbm2=h2o.gbm(training_frame = train_gb,validation_frame = valid_gb,x=1:51,y=52,
         model_id="gbm2_covType_v2",
         ntrees=200,
         max_depth = 30,
         sample_rate = .7,
         col_sample_rate = .7,
         learn_rate=.3,
         stopping_round=2,
         stopping_tolerance = .01,
         score_each_iteration = T,seed=2000000)
finalRF_prediction=h2o.predict(object=gbm2,newdata = test_gb)
summary(gbm2)
h2o.hit_ratio_table(gbm2,valid=T)[1,2]
mean(finalRF_prediction$predict==test_gb$Cover_Type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having a dataset to rerun your code on it's hard to say what caused the error. For your second error, check if the column `Cover_Type` exists in your test_gb dataframe.

The code you have seems to be fine, so I would just double check your column names.

In addition here is a code snippet with xgboost that shows you, you can use the hit_ratio_table() successfully.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
iris.hex <- h2o.importFile( "http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv")
i.sid <- h2o.runif(iris.hex)
iris.train <- h2o.assign(iris.hex[i.sid > .2, ], "iris.train")
iris.test <- h2o.assign(iris.hex[i.sid <= .2, ], "iris.test")
iris.xgboost.valid <- h2o.xgboost(x = 1:4, y = 5, training_frame = iris.train, validation_frame = iris.test)


# Hit ratio
hrt.valid.T <- h2o.hit_ratio_table(iris.xgboost.valid,valid = TRUE)
print(hrt.valid.T)
```